# Executar comando cURL em uma aplicação HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, libcurl

Tenho experiência zero em API, JSON, Ajax, cURL, o máximo que aprendi na faculdade foi básico de HTML, CSS, JS e PHP, já me matei de pesquisar e ver vídeo, mas sem ninguém com experiência para auxiliar fica difícil, já estou quase desistindo, preciso de alguma orientação.

Estou num projeto onde tenho que pegar os dados de um site por meio da API deles e jogar numa aplicação HTML/JS, seguindo os passos da documentação da API (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/chat/apis#real-time-chat-api), consegui puxar os dados por meio do cURL, que gera um JSON para mim, agora preciso saber como fazer essa requisição direto nessa aplicação HTML/JS, para que os dados apareçam direto no browser.

Quem puder ajudar, eu agradeço muito.

Edit: utilizei esse comando cURL

```
curl   https://rtm.zopim.com/stream/chats/active_chats \
-H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o cURL que utilizou? Você tem conhecimento sobre requisições HTTP assíncronas?

Comment: Muito pouco, tudo o que eu sei sobre esses assuntos (cURL, Ajax, JSON, etc) foi assistindo vídeos, vendo posts em fóruns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

São alguns passos que vão do frontend ao backend:

Primeiro você precisa do script PHP que faz a requisição para a API desse terceiro vamos chamá-lo de `chat.php` e supor que está hospedado com o domínio `https://meuexemplo.com.br/`. Sendo assim o seu recurso será o `https://meuexemplo.com.br/chat.php`

Arquivo chat.php:

```
<?php
// Faz alguma coisa (requisições com cURL por exemplo) para conseguir o JSON que deve aparecer no HTML
$resultado = array(); // coloquei um array vazio, mas vamos pensar que ele contêm os dados que devem ser direcionados para o HTML
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Agora que você montou o arquivo de backend que alimentará seu HTML/JS vamos ao Javascript, ou melhor, vamos utilizar o framework jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://meuexemplo.com.br/chat.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // A variável data contêm o JSON de resposta do seu backend.
      // Eu estou exemplificando que estamos acessando a chave 'teste' de data
      $('#resultado').html(data.test);
    }, error: function(err) {
      $('#resultado').html('Deu erro, porque não temos o backend neste exemplo');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Com os dados em formato JSON dentro de uma variável no `success` da função $.ajax você pode utilizar o jQuery para inserir as informações em uma tabela, div, ou seja, em qualquer parte do seu HTML (frontend).

Apesar de utilizar exemplos que não são reais se atente no processo, você possuí um script PHP que recupera os dados que você precisa e ele será acessado através de um JavaScript com o método `$.ajax` do jQuery. E, depois que o AJAX tiver os dados você utiliza JS/jQuery para alimentar sua interface em HTML.

Comment: Recebi voto contra, mas porque não deixa um comentário para que eu possa melhorar??

Comment: Entendi cara, muito obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar adaptar isso para o meu caso, valeu!

Obs: Não fui eu quem deu voto contra =/

Comment: Perfeito, deixe-me saber o progresso :)